# How do you restrict `resize()` from being called after constructing a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, collections, containers

I'm building a class that exposes a sequential container, with a fixed length, ***but the length isn't known at compile-time.***

So when an instance of my class is constructed, a parameter is passed in, to indicate how big the vector needs to be.

But the length needs to be fixed after construction.
I need to guarantee that the `resize()` function cannot be invoked, while still allowing other parts of my code to modify individual elements within the vector.
(In other words, I can't simply expose the vector as `vector<T> const&`)

The same goes for any other function which modifies the length, such as `insert()`, `push_back()`, etc.
These functions need to be restricted or hidden.

Is this possible?
Or do I really need to build my own `fixed_vector` wrapper class to hide the undesired functions?

Comment: If you don't want other code modifying the vector itself, then simply don't expose direct access to it. For instance, make the `vector` be a `private` member of another class, and then expose methods in that class to just modify the vector's elements as needed (or at least, to provide references/pointers to the elements).

Comment: You can use `std::make_unique<T[]>(size);` to create a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, a `unique_ptr` to an array of `T` of size `size`.

Comment: It seems you want to give `std::span` the outside.

Comment: @273K That looks perfect so far! I'm looking at it now. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++20 you can return a `std::span` to the range in the vector. This allows access to the size and modifiable access to the elements, but not the `vector`'s modifiers.

For example:

```
#include<vector>
#include<span>

class A {
    std::vector<int> vec;
public:
    /*...*/
    auto getVec() {
        return std::span(vec);
    }
 };
```

The return value can be used as a range, but there is no access to the container interface.

Depending on the types and initialization required, you may also be able to use an array `std::unique_ptr` instead of a `std::vector` if you know the size won't change. However that doesn't store the size, which you would then need to store yourself:

```
#include<vector>
#include<span>

class A {
    std::size_t vec_size;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> vec;
public:
    A(std::size_t size) : vec_size(size), vec(std::make_unique<int[]>(size)) { }

    auto getVec() {
        return std::span(vec, vec_size);
    }
 };
```

This may be slightly more space efficient since it doesn't require accounting for a difference in vector size and capacity.

Comment: Before C++20 (where this is no `span`) the approach is to avoid exposing the vector outside the containing class (no references, etc) and provide whatever operations are needed to access/modify elements (or sets of elements).